# Netty SSL server and client

Tags: netty

Seems like server denies tls negotiation from the wireshark output but I fail to see why from the code. It is based on code that worked, only it was deprecated and I therefore update with new API. The code is to get started. Need to use real certificates. Does anyone see why the server sends tcp FIN, ACK?

I have this server code:

```
    ServerBootstrap sbssl = new ServerBootstrap();
    bossGroupSsl = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    workerGroupSsl = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    sbssl.group(bossGroupSsl, workerGroupSsl).option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 8192).handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))
            .option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(8192))
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline cp = ch.pipeline();
                    SelfSignedCertificate cert = new SelfSignedCertificate();
                    SslContext cont2 = SslContextBuilder.forServer(cert.privateKey(), cert.certificate()).build();
                    SSLEngine engine = cont2.newEngine(ch.alloc());
                    cp.addLast("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
```

and this client code:

```
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        Log.d(RegisterAttemptSSL.class.getName(), "connecting");
        InetSocketAddress ria = new InetSocketAddress(toHostname, portDestination);
        b.group(group).channel(NioSocketChannel.class).option(ChannelOption.IP_TOS, 24)
                .remoteAddress(ria).handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                SslContext cont2 = SslContextBuilder.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();
                SSLEngine engine = cont2.newEngine(ch.alloc(), toHostname, portDestination);
                engine.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.2"});
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new SslHandler(engine, false));
```

Resulting in this wireshark:

21    16.840654    10.1.10.100    10.1.10.203    TCP    74    4683 → 5061 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=62567382 TSecr=0 WS=256

22    16.840931    IntelCor_25:1d:fc    Broadcast    ARP    42    Who has 10.1.10.100? Tell 10.1.10.203

23    16.856111    SonyMobi_7f:55:af    IntelCor_25:1d:fc    ARP    42    10.1.10.100 is at 84:c7:ea:7f:55:af

24    16.856198    10.1.10.203    10.1.10.100    TCP    74    5061 → 4683 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1 TSval=46199014 TSecr=62567382

25    16.859326    10.1.10.100    10.1.10.203    TCP    66    4683 → 5061 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=87808 Len=0 TSval=62567385 TSecr=46199014

26    16.872274    10.1.10.100    10.1.10.203    TLSv1    179    Client Hello

27    16.964375    10.1.10.203    10.1.10.100    TCP    66    5061 → 4683 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=114 Win=66560 Len=0 TSval=46199026 TSecr=62567387

28    16.965112    10.1.10.203    10.1.10.100    TCP    54    5061 → 4683 [RST, ACK] Seq=2 Ack=114 Win=0 Len=0

netty 4.1.18.Final
Win 7
jdk 8

With this code on server side it works except for channelReadComplete beeing triggered without channelRead0 of the next handler beeing triggered first one extra time. Same handler is used for regular tcp and works fine without this quirk. On client side there is a nullpointer but the business logic is not affected.

```
    ServerBootstrap sbssl = new ServerBootstrap();
    bossGroupSsl = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
    workerGroupSsl = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    sbssl.group(bossGroupSsl, workerGroupSsl).option(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, 8192)
            .option(ChannelOption.RCVBUF_ALLOCATOR, new FixedRecvByteBufAllocator(8192))
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class).handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))
            .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline cp = ch.pipeline();
                    SelfSignedCertificate cert = new SelfSignedCertificate();
                    SslContext cont = SslContext.newServerContext(cert.certificate(), cert.privateKey());
                    cp.addLast("ssl", cont.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
```

01-26 15:34:34.546 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.NullPointerException: ssl == null
01-26 15:34:34.546 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:459)
01-26 15:34:34.546 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
01-26 15:34:34.546 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
01-26 15:34:34.546 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
01-26 15:34:34.546 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
01-26 15:34:34.546 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:141)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:580)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:497)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: ssl == null
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_pending_readable_bytes(Native Method)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.pendingInboundCleartextBytes(OpenSSLEngineImpl.java:491)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.unwrap(OpenSSLEngineImpl.java:679)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.unwrap(OpenSSLEngineImpl.java:630)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLEngineImpl.unwrap(OpenSSLEngineImpl.java:596)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:292)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1248)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1159)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1194)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:489)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:     at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:428)
01-26 15:34:34.547 31823-31856/no.tobiassenit.sipclient W/System.err:   ... 16 more

Seems the problem occurs even though the new api is not used - just activating the classes is enough. So this works:Seems the problem occurs even though the new api is not used - just activating the classes is enough. So this works:

```
                    SelfSignedCertificate cert = new SelfSignedCertificate();
                    SslContext cont = SslContext.newServerContext(cert.certificate(), cert.privateKey());
                    //SslContext cont2 = SslContextBuilder.forServer(cert.privateKey(), cert.certificate()).build();
                    //SSLEngine engine = cont2.newEngine(ch.alloc());
                    //engine.setUseClientMode(true);;
                    //cp.addFirst("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
                    cp.addFirst("ssl", cont.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
```

while this does not (tcp fin, ack):

```
                    SelfSignedCertificate cert = new SelfSignedCertificate();
                    SslContext cont = SslContext.newServerContext(cert.certificate(), cert.privateKey());
                    SslContext cont2 = SslContextBuilder.forServer(cert.privateKey(), cert.certificate()).build();
                    SSLEngine engine = cont2.newEngine(ch.alloc());
                    //cp.addFirst("ssl", new SslHandler(engine));
                    cp.addFirst("ssl", cont.newHandler(ch.alloc()));
```

Comment: Seems like there is a NullPointerException. I would investigate there.

Comment: Note that the nullpointer occurs when the serverside is configured with the deprecated method  SslContext.newServerContext.

Comment: Also note that openssl is used by Android/client side and JSSE on server side.

Answer (score 1):

Netty 4.1.20.Final solves the server-not-responding problem. Still the ChannelComplete is called several times on the server side and there is a nullpointer on the client side. None of these affect the functionality of the client-server process.